# Updating Widget from external file

Tags: flutter, dart

For example I have a Widget in the **first.dart** file and another widget in the **second.dart** file. The first widget is a simple Button and the second Widget includes a Container with the color red. How can I change the color of this container when I tap the button?

If both widgets are in one file it would be of course very simple, just call the setState() method. But as I said each widget is on a separate file.

What I've tried? Honestly, nothing much. I'm not sure if this is even possible. My first idea was to use something like [ValueListenable](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ValueListenableBuilder-class.html) but the result was not really great.

Comment: @creativecreatorormaybenot No, I'm just splitting my code in two files. It's encouraged to have as little code as possible in main.dart and all the other code split into various files, isn't?

Comment: I would suggest learning about State Management with Flutter through this tutorial: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to create a new dart file with a stateless widget, set it to receive arguments with `final _color` and `ColoredContainer(this._color)` as shown:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ColoredContainer extends StatelessWidget {

  final _color;
  ColoredContainer(this._color);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: 100,
      height: 100,
      color: _color,
    );
  }
}
```

Then in the main.dart file, import the dart file and use `ColoredContainer` as a widget which you can pass the `Colors` to it, in my case I passed a different `Color` from a list of colors every time `setState` is called:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'ColoredContainer.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int index = 0;

  final List<Color> _colorList = [
    Colors.red,
    Colors.green,
    Colors.blue,
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            RaisedButton(onPressed: (){
              setState(() {
                index += 1;
              });
            }, child: Text('Tap me')),
            ColoredContainer(_colorList[index]),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you! Must be `ColoredContainer` a statelesswidget or could be a statefulwidget too?

Comment: @lucasjr It can be either stateless or stateful, both will work. But if you are going to use it as a widget that is called from the main.dart file, it is better to use stateless widget and control the state in the main.dart file. If my answer helped, please accept it as answer, thank you!